# Para que serve a meta description?E como o usa?

Tags: html, html5

Estava andando por uns sites e me deparei que usavam desta metatag:

```
<'meta name="description" content="...">
```

Queria entender mais do uso dele e onde ele ocorre.

Answer (score 1):

A Meta Description é o texto geralmente utilizado pelo Google para a exibição dos resultados de texto das segundas e terceiras linhas dos resultados de busca, logo abaixo do Título. O conteúdo da *meta description* não influencia no posicionamento de uma página no Google. Logo, não é necessário repetir palavras-chave nesta tag. Apesar de não interferir no posicionamento, uma descrição bem redigida e atrativa contribui para uma taxa de cliques (CTR - clickThrough Rate) mais alta, e este sim acredita-se ser um dos fatores utilizados pelo Google para aumentar o posicionamento de um resultado. Além disso, alguns termos da descrição são enfatizados em negrito, quando fazem parte da pesquisa realizada, ajudando o usuário a encontrar rapidamente o que está buscando com mais facilidade.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Caso usasse em uma página que não esteja alocada na web, mas no meu localhost. Pra que serviria isto?

Comment: Meta tags são linhas de código HTML que descrevem o conteúdo do seu site para os buscadores. Logo.... Se não estão na web, não serve pra nada